# How can I get the userid from the authorization token in the request so I can use it in a DbConnectionInterceptor?

Tags: entity-framework, thread-safety, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using .Net Core 3.1 Web API and Entity Framework on top of Postgres.  I want to write a userid from the auth token sent with the current request to the database as a session variable whenever a connection is opened so I can read it from an audit trigger and log any changes made in the database with the userid that made them.  I can write a session variable in postgres whenever a connection is opened like this.

```
public class DbUserIdProvider : DbConnectionInterceptor
{
    public string userid = "defaultid";

    // Called just after EF has called OpenAsync().
    public override Task ConnectionOpenedAsync(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEndEventData eventData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = $"set session.client_user_id to '{userid}'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return base.ConnectionOpenedAsync(connection, eventData, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to set userid to the value I can grab from the HttpRequest in a thread safe way without blocking other requests. I can use an ActionFilter and write the userid directly to the DbUserIdProvider, or use an event to do it. But when I get two concurrent requests the second overwrites the userid of the first and it writes the wrong id. And I don't want to block access to it for the duration of a request for obvious performance reasons.

Is there a way to associate a userid with a database connectionid?  Is there a way to get the HttpContext in a ConnectionInterceptor?  How can I make this work?  Or is there a different approach for what I want that would work better than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a clean way to do exactly what I want.  I found the key bit of information in [this answer](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21578#issuecomment-693675853) in github issues for efcore.

The setup looks like this.  You start with a Middleware that grabs the unique id of the requestor from the token passed in the header.  Middleware has singleton lifetime.  But you can use it with a scoped lifetime service by injecting the scoped service in the InvokeAsync method.

```
public class UserInfoMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public UserInfoMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    // Middleware has singleton lifetime. Adding a scoped service (UserInfoService) to the signature of 
    // InvokeAsync allows this middleware to write the userid from each request to the scoped UserInfoService
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, UserInfoService userInfo)
    {
        // here we read the user info from the Authorization header on the request
        var authHeaders = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        // you can load the app before logging in, but you can't access the database
        if (authHeaders.Count > 0 && authHeaders[0].StartsWith("Bearer "))
        {
            var jwt = authHeaders[0].Substring(7);
            JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(jwt);
            userInfo.uniqueName = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.ToArray().FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Type, "unique_name")).Value;
        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        await _next(context);
    }
}

public static class UserInfoMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseUserInfoMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<UserInfoMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

So now you have a (trivial) service that just holds the user's uniqueName from the token on a per-request basis.  You need to get that service to a scoped DbConnectionInterceptor so it can inject the user name into the database session when it opens the connection.  But the DbContextOptionsBuilder.AddInterceptors() method only accepts constructed instances, so if you use it at startup in the normal way you end up with a singleton. To get around this you need to use the AddDbContext overload that takes an Action<IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder> in the ConfigureServices method of your startup.cs file, like this.

```
// The UserInfoService holds the user's unique id for the duration of the request
// The id is set in the UserInfoMiddleware
services.AddScoped<UserInfoService>();
// The DbUserIdInterceptor is injected into the dbContext below
services.AddScoped<DbUserIdInterceptor>();

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((provider, options) =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(applicationSettings.ConnectionString());
    // Resolve the DbUserIdInterceptor from the service provider
    options.AddInterceptors(provider.GetRequiredService<DbUserIdInterceptor>());
});
```

Don't forget to add the middleware in Configure() like this

```
app.UseUserInfoMiddleware();
```

With those things set up you just need to modify the DbConnectionInterceptor to accept the UserIdService via DI, like so.

```
public class DbUserIdInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
{
    UserInfoService userInfoService;
    public DbUserIdInterceptor(UserInfoService uis)
    {
        userInfoService = uis;
    }

    // Called just after EF has called OpenAsync().
    public override Task ConnectionOpenedAsync(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEndEventData eventData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = $"set session.client_user_id to '{userInfoService.uniqueName}'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return base.ConnectionOpenedAsync(connection, eventData, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And that's it.  With all this in place you will be grabbing the unique name from the token in the request and setting it on the session in the database every time you open a connection.

Answer (score 0):

The interceptors are pretty weak at giving you additional context like this.

But luckily, you really don't want use an interceptor for this.

Since you're adding an extra command each time the connection is opened, you should prevent the connection from being opened and closed multiple times in a DbContext.  The way you do that is you open the connection in DbContext.OnConfiguring and close it in DbContext.Dispose(), something like:

```
SqlConnection con = null;
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var constr = "Server = localhost; database = efcore3test; integrated security = true";
    con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    
    optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
                  .UseSqlServer(con, o => o.UseRelationalNulls().UseNetTopologySuite());


    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
public override void Dispose()
{
    con.Dispose();
    base.Dispose();
}
```

And if you've got an open connection at that point, you can set the session context.