# Getting HttpContext (or just user information) into DbConnectionInterceptor in .Net Core 6 with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, interceptor, asp.net-core-6.0, row-level-security

I am trying to setup RLS by running *sp_set_session_context* at the point of connection to my SQL Server database via a **DbConnectionInterceptor**.  It works fabulously when I use a hardcoded Username, but I really need to pull the user's information from *User.Identity.Name*.  I cannot seem to find a way to pass the *HttpContext* into my **DbConnectionInterceptor**.

One way I tried was using DI like this:

```
public class EFConnectionInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor, IDbConnectionInterceptor
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
    public EFConnectionInterceptor(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override Task ConnectionOpenedAsync(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEndEventData eventData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var Username = _context.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
        if (Username != null)
        {
            DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "EXEC sp_set_session_context @key=N'Username', @value=@Username";
            DbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@Username";
            param.Value = Username;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And then calling AddDbContext in my Progam.cs with my Interceptor:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
  options
    .UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myconnstring"))
    .AddInterceptors(new EFConnectionInterceptor())
    );
```

But this fails to compile because it needs me to pass an *HttpContext* into the *new EFConnectionInterceptor()* call.  I don't seem to have access to GetRequiredService() from a provider at this point since I haven't built the service yet, so I don't know how to get it here.

How do I get a User Name into my Interceptor?

A completely different approach is fine too, as long as I efficiently call *sp_set_session_context* with the user's name before any database resources are accessed.

I'm using a DB First approach and *Scaffold-DbContext* to pull **hundreds** of database tables into the project so I'd prefer to not have to modify my *DbContext* (named *MyContext* above).

The Interceptor was a very tempting way to do this, but I just can't get the user information into it!

Note:
I did see this post:
[How can I get the userid from the authorization token in the request so I can use it in a DbConnectionInterceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059485/how-can-i-get-the-userid-from-the-authorization-token-in-the-request-so-i-can-us)
But it has the same issue with the middleware solution since I can't do this:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((provider, options) =>
{
    // [...]
    options.AddInterceptors(provider.GetRequiredService<DbUserIdInterceptor>());
});
```

because *(provider,options)* does not work in .net Core 6 the way I am building in Program.cs -- I have no "provider" at the point in the build.

Comment: _"because (provider,options) does not work in .net Core 6 "_ - can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your `EFConnectionInterceptor` can replace the `DbUserIdInterceptor` in the link you mentioned. Did you get any errors?

Comment: "because (provider,options) does not work in .net Core 6 " There is no "provider" object at the point in program.cs that this line is created.  I don't know where I would find it.  So you just get a compiler error because it doesn't know what "provider" is. This all happens well before 
...
var app = builder.Build() 
...
GetRequiredService would not exist yet because it hasn't been built yet.  

And to be clear I'm pretty new at the whole "no startup.cs" way of doing things so if I have it wrong PLEASE correct me!  :)  This is only my 3rd project with the "minimal" program.cs concept.

Comment: Chen - I ran into the same problem of not having a provider object to run the GetRequiredService to pull in the middleware component.  Again, that example was run in the less "minimal" style that 6.0 is now using.  But if I have the ability to call GetRequiredService for the middleware I shouldn't need it because could just pass the Interceptor which is what I think you're saying.  I don't have a "provider" to use in the minimal structure that I have.  Maybe that is my problem here...it's my inexperience with the minimal structured program.cs.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me in Asp.net Core7

```
 public partial class PlanContext : DbContext
{
    public PlanContext()
    {
    }

    public PlanContext(DbContextOptions<PlanContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Tplan> Tplans { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Tplanlog> Tplanlogs { get; set; }

    public static string UNAME { get; set; }
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=serv1;Database=Db1;User ID=U1; Password=Pass; TrustServerCertificate=True");
        optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new AppDbConnectionInterceptor());
        UNAME = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }

    public PlanContext(DbContextOptions<PlanContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
: base(options)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public class AppDbConnectionInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
    {
        public AppDbConnectionInterceptor() { }
        public override async Task ConnectionOpenedAsync(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEndEventData eventData,  CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var Logonuser = UNAME; 
            var keyParameter = new SqlParameter("Key", Logonuser);
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_set_session_context 'UNAME', @key;", (SqlConnection)connection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(keyParameter);
            await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }

/////////////

}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to authenticate requests to Azure SQL from Blazor Server.  I got it by creating a new `HttpContextAccessor` (without adding it to the DI container) and passing it to my `DbConnectionInterceptor`.

```cs
// .NET 6/7/8 Program.cs
....

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://database.windows.net/user_impersonation", "User.Read" };
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(scopes)
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

....

// Create a new HttpContextAccessor but don't add it to the DI container.
var httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<AutotaskDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnStr"));
    options.AddInterceptors(
        new AadAuthDbConnectionInterceptor(() =>
        {
            return httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
        })
    );
});
```

```cs
public class AadAuthDbConnectionInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
{
    protected Func<string> _getToken;

    public AadAuthDbConnectionInterceptor(Func<string> getToken)
    {
        _getToken = getToken;
    }

    public override InterceptionResult ConnectionOpening(
        DbConnection connection,
        ConnectionEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult result)
    {
        var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)connection;
        if (DoesConnectionNeedAccessToken(sqlConnection))
        {
            // Use the access token to authenticate the connection.
            sqlConnection.AccessToken = _getToken.Invoke();
        }

        return base.ConnectionOpening(connection, eventData, result);
    }

    ....
}
```